# TypeScript generic extending some Array type accepting unrelated type problem

Tags: typescript

I have some function similar to the following mock.

```js
// All properties in this type are optional.
interface MyType {
  a?: string
}

// The type of the return result of `cb` is kept as the final result type.
const f = <T extends ReadonlyArray<MyType>>(cb: (() => T)): T => cb()

const myTests1 = f(() => [1, {}]) // no error, but it really should
const myTests2 = f(() => [{}]) // no error
const myTests3 = f(() => [{}] as const) // no error
const myTests4 = f(() => [1]) // error
const myTests5 = f(() => [1, {}] as const) // error
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBtNAHAnA9rApvALgSxQZ1JgO1HQAtM90BPVUAQ3hVGS0QNsgDoAoQ9NAM1oBjRgFlKAFWqMA3l1B0A-AC5QOdPEIBzLgF8uXEKAklGVGon7FToBugCu8Igxz3I6JlYAGQgEZf8PABrFFgPWgobfkJ2W1w3D3MUbiFWdVArAF5QAB4JUBQADz4CABM8ACUUWlLWSEpweHhaShzxKVQAPk6ACj9VHp6ASlBMzuMhodV8sdA-YYNUgnSAW0lcdBwARlGMwZHZgG0tgBpQGV0AXRGjAkQCpsR4M997D0wPBnZ6tRJEN1KXCWq3W6hwACZdvx9qNxocLtdQLd7mgkPAgWkPGsJBscABmKEwo4Iuh4YHoG5gO4PNEY5ZY0GbAAshOGsNAx0RRlRTzpIJxYIArKyDnDTucrqS5pjKTSnkA)

I intend for the `cb` function to return only items that are of `MyType`s. The `f` function is sort of a type safe data model builder I intend to build that users can use to declare the complex `MyType` with type safety.

I know that TypeScript only really cares about the duck type and not the JS type strictly, so e.g. there would be no error when I say `const x: {} = 1`. And by experimenting, my typing issue was gone if any property in `MyType` is required.

But my question are:

- How is the TS compiler OK with `myTest1` but not with `myTests4` or `myTests5`?
- Is there a way to redefine the typing of the above function that would disallow users returning any items in `cb` that is not an object?

Comment: `1` inferred as `number` in first example, `number` is assignable to `{}` (almost everything is). But in the examples with `as const` it is now the literal type `1`, which is not assignable to `{}`.

Comment: Are you really going to be handing in empty objects like `{}` a lot?  The type `{}` is special-cased to not complain about non-overlap, absorbs all non-`null` or `undefined` element types in an array, and is seen as assignable to `object`.  You could refactor like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnQzow) if that meets your needs.  But it might not be worth chasing down empty objects unless that's a common use case.  If you want me to write up an answer with the above refactor and explaining what's going on, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz yes please. Would you mind explaining why returning `[...T]` works as expected but `T` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript type system isn't completely [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), so there are some inconsistencies that people occasionally trip over.  [Assignability/compatibility/subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out) should be [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), so if `X extends Y` is true and `Y extends Z` is true then `X extends Z` should also be true.  But this is sometimes violated in TypeScript:

```
let x: number = 1; 
let y: {} = x; // okay
let z: { a?: string } = y; // okay

z = x; // error!
```

Here you can see that while `y = x` is allowed, and `z = x` is allowed, the direct assignment `z = x` is prohibited.  This inconsistency is responsible for the weirdness you're seeing.  If the compiler notices that you are widening `number` to `{a?: string}` it will complain, but if there is an intermediate widening to `{}` it will not complain.

In

```
const myTests1 = f(() => [1, {}])
```

the compiler takes the array literal `[1, {}]` and infers it to have the type `{}[]`.  This is [inference to the "best common type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) of `number` and `{}`, which is `{}`.  At this point you've lost, since from then on the compiler makes sure that `{}` is assignable to `{a?: string}`, which it is, and no error occurs.

To some extent, this built-in inconsistency means that there's no way to prevent the kind of problem you're seeing in all situations.  All you can hope to do is work around it and perhaps change your definition of `f()` to make the problem less likely to appear.

---

One way to do so might be as follows:

```
const f = <T extends MyType[]>(
  cb: (() => readonly [...T])
): readonly [...T] => cb()
```

Here I've replaced `T` with `readonly [...T]`.  This is a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which is nearly the same as `T`.  But when the compiler sees `[...T]` it takes it as a hint that it should try to infer a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instead of an unordered array type.

And so then the array literal `[1, {}]` is inferred to be of the type `[number, {}]` instead of `{}[]`.  And this preserves the `number` type long enough for the compiler to notice that it is not assignable to `{a?: string}`:

```
const myTests1 = f(() => [1, {}]) // error!
// ---------------------> ~
// Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'MyType'.
```

There are observable differences between `T` and `readonly [...T]` (e.g., if `T` is not `readonly` then `readonly [...T]` will be) so this approach might not work for all possible use cases.  And even with this approach, all it does is make the issue less likely; it doesn't eliminate it:

```
const myTests6 = f(() => {
  const ret = [1, {}]; // const ret: {}[]
  return ret;
}) // no error
```

Here, the type of `ret` is inferred to be `{}[]` inside the body of the callback function, independently of how `f()` is typed.  [Contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) can't reach back through the `return ret` line to the definition of `ret`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBtNAHAnA9rApvALgSxQZ1JgO1HQAtM90BPVUAQ3hVGS0QNsgDoAoQ9NAM1oBjRgFlKAFWqMA3l1B0A-AC5QOdPEIBzLgF8uXEKAklGVGon7FToBugCu8Igxz3I6JlYAGQgEZf8PABrFFgPWgobfkJ2W1w3D3MUbiFWdVArAF5QAB4JUBQADz4CABM8cSlUAG0AXQA+AAp5UD9VRsaASlBM+rjaUtZISlBqjnGJWs6uTtUGAaGRsYnanr6-LoNUgnSAW0lcdBwARh6Mju7e0eOAGlAZXSnQIzQkeABCQzAAWl+--4BgL6AD8vsZpKAAOQEey7XxoSGgEgRUAERBwJCoDDYPCEVqIXa7VigADumFIxAhkMq0kh3C42z2B3UOAATGd+Bc1qMHk8jGiCvA3gy0h59hJDjgAMwcrlXaq8uh4Rnobr89GvRDwEU7MXMo4AFllXW51WOfLAmu1KtA4slAFZjZc+ma7oqUSq1ZahVqDFxICgPIVVDC4WgzscANz+wOgSiqB5nQqR55gRBBWiUGMeABeCaUqnUmgIWlAujOlBTRnTmYMOaTVe9wp1TIlLIAbE7uXIFDa7GdXfdHo38bq4ugE7o6i07I5nIHo7pOkA)